# Why does Masonry add a right margin to a layout with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry, masonry

When using Masonry (v3.2.2), it adds an unnecessary right margin that renders the masonry unable to be centered on the page. It also does the same thing without a 'container-fluid' class, with just 'container'.

HTML: (I also am loading the most recent version of Masonry and ImagesLoaded

```
    <div class="container-fluid" id="content_container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="masonry js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 350, "gutter": 0}'>
              <div class="item w2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></div>
              <div class="item w3"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></div>
              <!-- etc...until 8 images are rendered -->
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
 width: 350px;
 margin: 0px;
 float: left;}

 .item.w2 { width:  350px; }
 .item.w3 { width:  350px; }
 .item.w4 { width:  350px; }
```

In Firefox's inspect element, it clearly shows this extra margin being added. Inspecting the code, there is nothing generating any margin/padding. Note the lighter blue is the additional padding and the white area is the normal gutter from the bootstrap container. Ideally, the white area would be the same on each side, centering the masonry layout.

View image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNSKh.jpg

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jco4xrvr/2/

Comment: You need to post your masonry code. An image is not enough. ALso, what version of Masonry are you usiing?

Comment: I have updated the original question with the version (v3.2.2). I have provided the HTML/css, what else is needed? The image was to visually demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You need to provide the javascript you use to call masonry.That is not in the html or css. The best option for questions like this is to make a jsfiddle or codepen. Images are not enough to answer most questions.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have updated it to include a jsfiddle. I believe I have included all the necessary components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/qxutcbms/).

Basically you need to use isFitWidth and set the css for your masonry container:

HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid" id="content_container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="masonry js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 350, "gutter": 0,"isFitWidth": true}'>
            <div class="item w2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
            </div>
            <div class="item w3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
            </div>
            <div class="item w4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
            </div>
            <div class="item w4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
            </div>
            <div class="item w4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
            </div>
            <div class="item w4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
            </div>
            <div class="item w4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
            </div>
            <div class="item w4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

add this CSS:

```
.masonry {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you for your solution. For others with this problem I found this explaining it a bit more if needed. http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#isfitwidth